# Display String as HTML

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

How can I render a string to be displayed as an html?
I am trying to accept an array of strings. I should be able to check if the string is an html, if yes, I need to display it with html formatting, otherwise display normally as a string.

Example:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="msg in msgs" :key="msg">
    {{ msg }}
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
// msgs will look like this:
const msgs = ['hello there', '<b>print this in bold</b>', '<br/>', 'and this is in another line']
```

I tried to do something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="msg in msgs" :key="msg">
     {{ isHtml(msg) ? processAsHtml(msg) : msg }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Where `processAsHtml` is like this:

```js
const parser = new DOMParser()

function processAsHtml (htmlString) {
  return parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html')
}
```

But this prints the html lines as "[object HTMLDocument]"

Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use v-html

```
<template>
  <div v-for="msg in msgs" :key="msg">
     <div v-html="msg">
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other suggested, Just to print the row HTML in the template you can directly use [`v-html`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html) directive.

But If you want to check that which strings are normal strings and which are not a normal. That you can check with the help of regex and [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msgs: ['hello there', '<b>print this in bold</b>', '<br/>', 'and this is in another line']
  },
  mounted() {
    this.msgs.forEach(str => {
        if (str.match(/(<[^>]+>|<\/>)/ig)) {
        console.log('Not a mornal string : ', str);
      } else {
        console.log('Normal string : ', str);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="msg in msgs" :key="msg" v-html="msg">
  </div>
</div>
```

***Note :*** As [`Nikola`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11989189/nikola-pavicevic) suggested, Kindly check for the XSS Vulnerabilities in this case. Best practice is to sanitize the strings which is not normal before binding in HTML.